# what now... when alsa force-unload fails

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa

I'm having trouble with the sound on my laptop. (Not sure if it is platform specific, I have a System76 Lemur).

```
james at james in ~
$ sudo alsa unload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-core snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-core snd-pcm snd-timer).

james at james in ~
$ sudo alsa force-unload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-core snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-core snd-pcm snd-timer).
```

In trying to troubleshoot a fix I tried reloading ALSA `sudo alsa force-reload` that unfortunately failed, stating some modules were still loaded. So I then ran the above commands.

How can I reload the modules that failed to unload ?